# Friendly URLs in Yii

Tags: php, url, yii

I'm writing a project in Yii.

I need to create rules to show categories.

The URL has to be like: `http://localhost/frontend/web/c/category1/category2`

I can access the correct page with the URL: `http://localhost/frontend/web/categorias/view?id=category1/category2`

I've read the documentation, but I cannot find the correct guide.

I have tried:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '<c:\w+><id:\d+>'=>'<categorias>/view',
    ]
],
```

AND

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'c/<id:\d+>'=>'categorias/view',
    ]
],
```

But it doesn't work, I get an error

> An Error occurred while handling another error:
>   exception 'yii\base\ViewNotFoundException' with message 'The view file does not exist: [project_route]/error.php

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it using two rules, two methods that call to another

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'c/<category:[\w\-]+>'=>'categorias/view-first',
            'c/<category1:[\w\-]+>/<category2:[\w\-]+>'=>'categorias/view-second',
        ]
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear about the part with `category1/category2`. I will give you answers based on different interpretations of it.

**1) It's a list of multiple categories names or IDs (one or more)**

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'c/<categories>'=>'categorias/view',
    ]
],
```

You should prepare `actionView` in `CategoriasController` to be something like:

```
public function actionView($categories)
{
    $categoryList = explode('/', $categories);
    // ...the rest of action
}
```

Now `$categoryList` is the array of passed `$categories` either the names or IDs depending on what you use.

**2) It's a list of exactly two category names (no more, no less)**

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'c/<name1:[\w\-]+>/<name2:[\w\-]+>'=>'categorias/view',
    ]
],
```

You should prepare `actionView` in `CategoriasController` to be something like:

```
public function actionView($name1, $name2)
{
    // ...the rest of action
}
```

Passed categories are words with optional dashes.

**3) It's a list of exactly two category IDs (no more, no less)**

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'c/<id1:\d+>/<id2:\d+>'=>'categorias/view',
    ]
],
```

You should prepare `actionView` in `CategoriasController` to be something like:

```
public function actionView($id1, $id2)
{
    // ...the rest of action
}
```

Passed categories are integeres.